# FB Connect: is there a way to see the logged in user's facebook apps?

Tags: facebook

i was wondering if it was possible to fetch a list of a user's facebook application ids via the graph api.

after looking at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user, it looks as though it is not a possible connection, but i want to ask the pros before i am completely shut down =(

thanks!

Comment: why would you want to violate someone's privacy like that... not that there's privacy with Facebook anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by user's apps? Apps user developed? Apps user authorized?

Comment: To put it less bluntly, what could possibly be a valid use case for that? It would more likely be hugely abused more than correctly used in edge cases in which it would be appropriate.

Comment: i just want to know if the person logged in likes playing mob wars or whatnot. is it really that bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most you can do is retrieve a list of applications the current user is a fan of, by running FQL on [`page_fan`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan) table:

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid = 12345
```

If a user enjoys some app there is a good chance that he or she might be a fan of it.