# Facebook: detecting user apps

Tags: facebook, detect

Hello I've read the docs and am having trouble getting a definitive answer for the following questions:

1. Can our app detect if another app is used by a given user.  What about if we are admin of, or have the id of both apps.
2. If one of the apps is removed from FB is there a way to tell if a user had it installed before it was removed?  A sort of history of past apps, I guess.

Here:
[FB Connect: is there a way to see the logged in user's facebook apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234107/fb-connect-is-there-a-way-to-see-the-logged-in-users-facebook-apps)

Best answer is "**I think** the most you can do..." but I'd like to know for sure.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you request the permission **user_actions:APP_NAMESPACE** you can see the open graph actions that the user has performed in that app.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#open_graph_perms

In my apps I generally store the user ID of all authorized users in a database, and when I get a call via the "Deauthorize Callback URL" I don't delete the user from the database, but instead only flag the user as deauthorized.

This way I can easily get an overview of users that are using (or have used) any of my apps. This allows me to present special features for users who are using several of my apps.

For example, let's say I made a photo app (like Instagram) and a GPS running app (like Endomondo). If the user takes a photo with Instagram while running with Endomondo, I could present the option to GPS-tag the photo, or add the photo to Endomondo.

This is something that I think we developers should use more. Perhaps present an open API to other apps, to let the apps work together.